# How to handle many independent tasks which are repeated at different intervals in a worker?

Tags: c#, .net, task, worker, cancellation-token

I am trying to make **a simple monitoring service in .NET 6.0**.

For the sake of simplicity, I can describe the basics of the service like this: I have **request (Url, method, and interval)** and **response** tables in my database.

I have two workers. **The first worker** (let's say **"collector worker"**) **reads the requests from the database and adds them to a concurrent dictionary, which the second worker will use** (let's say **"sender worker"**).

Currently, **sender worker reads the requests from the concurrent dictionary, and creates a task which will repeatedly send the request with a given interval** (if the interval is 1 minute, it sends the request every 1 minute).

Two problem arises at this point:

1. If the request count in the database increases to a certain level, I can imagine that this "one task for each request" will not work. If I try to group the requests with the same interval and send them together, then the delay of a single request will affect all other requests because of the usage of WhenAll(). **How do I redesign the system so it can handle that many requests?**
2. I didn't mention but if one of the requests is updated or deleted from the database, both workers will know this change and act accordingly, which means one of the ongoing tasks could be terminated or updated while others continue to work. Since each task has to be handled independently, just one cancellationToken cannot be used in this case, every task had to have its own cancellationToken, which means I have to keep a list of cancellationTokens. **Is this the best way to handle this problem or is there another way?**

Comment: *“Two problem arises at this point: If the request count in the database increases to a certain level, I can imagine that this "one task for each request" will not work.”* -- It seems that you are trying to tackle an imaginary problem. How about doing an experiment, in order to verify that the reality matches your imagination?

Answer (score 1):

1. `WhenAll` should not affect each contained task. It just waits for them all to finish. It would be no different than just awaiting each task one by one.
2. It doesn't sound great to terminate the tasks midway - that might leave the system in a weird state - might be better to perform an inverse operation to undo what was done rather than cancel something that might already be half done (it's difficult to know without more context/details).

Comment: 1. The thing is, all tasks are defined as async without await so that they don't wait for each other, that was my motivation for creating a different task for each request and that is why WhenAll may cause some problems.

2. Your answer gave me this idea: I can use the cancellationToken to terminate the task after it completes its last run ( I mean after writing the response to the database) so the system can be left in a stable state. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to await ```Task.WhenAll```

Comment: @YungDeiza why would you use the `Task.WhenAll` method, if you are not intending to `await` it?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If you want a clean way to group tasks and run them at the same time

Comment: ​@YungDeiza the `Task.WhenAll` doesn't cause the tasks to run, if that's what you mean. It has no visible effect to the tasks.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You're right, you'd still need to kick them off. I mainly mentioned it was mentioned in the original question. You could just loop through the tasks and kick them off without awaiting them or even use a parallel loop.